# Basic or UserDatabaseRealm with @servlet 3.0 annotations using Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to setup the security for one of our internal web applications.  I would like to setup either Basic or UserDatabaseRealm with the servlet 3.0 annotations.  I've already added the user and the passord along with the role in tomcat-users.xml.  I've used the @servletSecurity and @HttpConstraint along with the rolesallowed.  What happened is that the web application now says something like web page not available.  i was expecting a small popup window that would allow you to enter the user id and the password.  That didn't happen.  Even though i am using the servlet 3.0 annotations, do i still have to setup the web.xml for the security?

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)   
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class)
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = TransportGuarantee.NONE, rolesAllowed = {"MyUser"}))
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: i was doing @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class).  Then added "@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = TransportGuarantee.NONE,
    rolesAllowed = {"MyUser"}))".